# vSphere PowerCLI storage vMotion

Tags: vmware-vsphere, powercli

How do I svMotion a single disk in PowerCLI 5.5?

Trying `Set-HardDisk` gives the following warning:

```
WARNING: Parameter 'Datastore' is obsolete. 'Datastore' parameter is obsolete. To move hard disk to another datastore
and change it's storage format, use 'Move-HardDisk' cmdlet instead.
```

`Set-HardDisk` fails anyway with a message that the disk is locked (hence I guess you can't use it for an online migration).

`Move-HardDisk` only seems to be able to move disks in offline mode too (cold migration), however I'd like to perform a Storage vMotion.

`Move-VM` can only move *all* disks of a VM, which is not what I want. (Too many and too big disks on a VM, will never fit on one destination LUN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can't simply

```
Move-HardDisk $hd -Datastore $dstds
```

which will give a message that the disk is locked. But instead you can do something along the lines of:

```
Get-HardDisk -VM MyVM -Name 'Hard Disk 1' | Move-HardDisk -Datastore MyDS
```

which seems to carry out an svMotion just nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I use this in part of a longer script I wrote for a migration projects. This is pulling names and csv I built earlier in the same script.

```
Get-HardDisk -vm $line.Name | where {$_.filename -match $startDS} |Move-HardDisk -Datastore $endDS -Confirm:$false
```

Where:

- $line.Name = name of a VM
- $startDS = the current datastore I was evacuating
- &endDS = the datastore I was sending the drive to

This works for me on VMs regardless of the power state, but it does not move configuration files.